# Why are images not showing in Rails app deployed on Heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I have tried many solutions on here for similar question but none so far have worked. I thought at first I may need to migrate the database or precompile assets so I tried:

```
rails assets:precompile
bundle exec rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production
heroku run rails db:migrate
```

after each I pushed to git and heroku but still the background image for the page and for the navbar do not show.

I also have a few suspicions as to the problem, but I need help investigating them. The images are in the css file and not in application layout so this may be the cause, but I would have thought that `require tree.` in the application.scss would automatically include all stylesheets.

pages.scss:

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: justify;
    font: 12px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
    color: #061C37;
    background: #F7F8ED;
    background-image:url('background2.png');
    background-repeat:repeat-x;
}

#menu
{
background-image:url('menu.png');
background-repeat:no-repeat;
width:720px;
height:49px;
clear:both;
}
```

application_layout.rb:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Site1</title>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>

    <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1 class="off2">Nutricion</h1>
    <h2 class="off3">Simón Verde</h2>

<div id="container">
    <div id="menu">
      <ul>
        <li class="menuitem">
          <%= link_to 'Inicio', pages_inicio_path %>
        </li>
        <li class="menuitem">
          <%= link_to 'Page1', pages_page1_path %>
        </li>
        <li class="menuitem">
          <%= link_to 'Page2', pages_page2_path %>
        </li>
        <li class="menuitem">
          <%= link_to 'Page3', pages_page3_path %>
        </li>
        <li class="menuitem">
          <%= link_to 'Contacto', pages_contacto_path %>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    </div>

<div id="content">

    <%= yield %>

</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

The html for the pages in development (where images work) and production (where they don't work) are also different. As can be seen below it appears that the assets are not loading properly. I noticed that when I precompiled the assets they were compiled in the `public/assets` folder and not the `app/assets` folder. does this make a difference? If so, why is it doing it and how can I proceed? also a brief explanation of why asset precompiling is necessary would be appreciated to understand better what is going wrong here.

The final thing I noticed is that the names of the image files are different in the `public/assets` folder than in the `app/assets` folder i.e. `menu.png` has automatically changed to `menu-longlistofrandomcharacters.png` so this could be affecting the display of the images.

html source from development (working images):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Site1</title>
    <meta name="csrf-param" content="authenticity_token" />
<meta name="csrf-token" content="FaSScd+v4DcF0Qw1F+J4ncgTPYFVtZnGVSmbPLAbRepnLZWX5CVZ4Seu7MtM7zi9S/xvXAkX9C9S8PBaljPFag==" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/application-6c72f0201f5f7b2ee273bd419a0b5c2a9e23f4d82d24ac305819a8f8823d7041.css" data-turbolinks-track="reload" />
    <script src="/assets/application-5c96b667d84f4b133f713cdb7f070ec1c66c023d7b9a7c4da42e893764b2391e.js" data-turbolinks-track="reload"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1 class="off2">Nutricion</h1>
    <h2 class="off3">Simón Verde</h2>

<div id="container">
    <div id="menu">
      <ul>
        <li class="menuitem">
          <a href="/pages/inicio">Inicio</a>
        </li>
        <li class="menuitem">
          <a href="/pages/page1">Page1</a>
        </li>
        <li class="menuitem">
          <a href="/pages/page2">Page2</a>
        </li>
        <li class="menuitem">
          <a href="/pages/page3">Page3</a>
        </li>
        <li class="menuitem">
          <a href="/pages/contacto">Contacto</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    </div>

<div id="content">

    <h1>Pages#inicio-</h1>
<p>Find me in app/views/pages/inicio.html.erb</p>


</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

html source from production (non working images):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Site1</title>
    <meta name="csrf-param" content="authenticity_token" />
<meta name="csrf-token" content="GS80dnfxoO5mgrdm82ZPYZYf812BdzCUVEzCJ3bK94RMII673xzCG9UxNLxcmj/RzmuZXH/y7lWCXvP2DbaVMA==" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/pages.self-36f0aba003234ddc45e8dc02c89942085fbc533a2591c1fef108462ef36733ce.css?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="reload" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/application.self-af04b226fd7202dfc532ce7aedb95a0128277937e90d3b3a3d35e1cce9e16886.css?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="reload" />
    <script src="/assets/jquery.self-bd7ddd393353a8d2480a622e80342adf488fb6006d667e8b42e4c0073393abee.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="reload"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery_ujs.self-784a997f6726036b1993eb2217c9cb558e1cbb801c6da88105588c56f13b466a.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="reload"></script>
<script src="/assets/turbolinks.self-2db6ec539b9190f75e1d477b305df53d12904d5cafdd47c7ffd91ba25cbec128.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="reload"></script>
<script src="/assets/action_cable.self-5454023407ffec0d29137c7110917e1e745525ae9afbc05f52104c4cd6597429.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="reload"></script>
<script src="/assets/cable.self-6e0514260c1aa76eaf252412ce74e63f68819fd19bf740595f592c5ba4c36537.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="reload"></script>
<script src="/assets/pages.self-877aef30ae1b040ab8a3aba4e3e309a11d7f2612f44dde450b5c157aa5f95c05.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="reload"></script>
<script src="/assets/application.self-b89234cf2659d7fedea75bca0b8d231ad7dfc2f3f57fcbaf5f44ed9dc384137b.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="reload"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1 class="off2">Nutricion</h1>
    <h2 class="off3">Simón Verde</h2>

<div id="container">
    <div id="menu">
      <ul>
        <li class="menuitem">
          <a href="/pages/inicio">Inicio</a>
        </li>
        <li class="menuitem">
          <a href="/pages/page1">Page1</a>
        </li>
        <li class="menuitem">
          <a href="/pages/page2">Page2</a>
        </li>
        <li class="menuitem">
          <a href="/pages/page3">Page3</a>
        </li>
        <li class="menuitem">
          <a href="/pages/contacto">Contacto</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    </div>

<div id="content">

    <h1>Pages#inicio-</h1>
<p>Find me in app/views/pages/inicio.html.erb</p>


</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

config/production.rb

```
Rails.application.configure do
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb.

  # Code is not reloaded between requests.
  config.cache_classes = true

  # Eager load code on boot. This eager loads most of Rails and
  # your application in memory, allowing both threaded web servers
  # and those relying on copy on write to perform better.
  # Rake tasks automatically ignore this option for performance.
  config.eager_load = true

  # Full error reports are disabled and caching is turned on.
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true

  # Disable serving static files from the `/public` folder by default since
  # Apache or NGINX already handles this.
  config.public_file_server.enabled = ENV['RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES'].present?

  # Compress JavaScripts and CSS.
  config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier
  # config.assets.css_compressor = :sass

  # Do not fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed.
  config.assets.compile = false

  # `config.assets.precompile` and `config.assets.version` have moved to config/initializers/assets.rb

  # Enable serving of images, stylesheets, and JavaScripts from an asset server.
  # config.action_controller.asset_host = 'http://assets.example.com'

  # Specifies the header that your server uses for sending files.
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Sendfile' # for Apache
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Accel-Redirect' # for NGINX

  # Mount Action Cable outside main process or domain
  # config.action_cable.mount_path = nil
  # config.action_cable.url = 'wss://example.com/cable'
  # config.action_cable.allowed_request_origins = [ 'http://example.com', /http:\/\/example.*/ ]

  # Force all access to the app over SSL, use Strict-Transport-Security, and use secure cookies.
  # config.force_ssl = true

  # Use the lowest log level to ensure availability of diagnostic information
  # when problems arise.
  config.log_level = :debug

  # Prepend all log lines with the following tags.
  config.log_tags = [ :request_id ]

  # Use a different cache store in production.
  # config.cache_store = :mem_cache_store

  # Use a real queuing backend for Active Job (and separate queues per environment)
  # config.active_job.queue_adapter     = :resque
  # config.active_job.queue_name_prefix = "site1_#{Rails.env}"
  config.action_mailer.perform_caching = false

  # Ignore bad email addresses and do not raise email delivery errors.
  # Set this to true and configure the email server for immediate delivery to raise delivery errors.
  # config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false

  # Enable locale fallbacks for I18n (makes lookups for any locale fall back to
  # the I18n.default_locale when a translation cannot be found).
  config.i18n.fallbacks = true

  # Send deprecation notices to registered listeners.
  config.active_support.deprecation = :notify

  # Use default logging formatter so that PID and timestamp are not suppressed.
  config.log_formatter = ::Logger::Formatter.new

  # Use a different logger for distributed setups.
  # require 'syslog/logger'
  # config.logger = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(Syslog::Logger.new 'app-name')

  if ENV["RAILS_LOG_TO_STDOUT"].present?
    logger           = ActiveSupport::Logger.new(STDOUT)
    logger.formatter = config.log_formatter
    config.logger = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(logger)
  end

  # Do not dump schema after migrations.
  config.active_record.dump_schema_after_migration = false
end
```

Could someone also explain why all the extra lines of html  tags dont appear on the non working version?

Comment: images aren't in the root directory so makes sense they wouldn't be showing

Comment: @WilliamHampshire by 'root directory' do you mean the app directory? because they are in there. it is just when precompiling Rails automatically used the public directory. I am not sure what to do about this

Comment: can you show your rendered HTML code for  `#menu`? See if the background-image has the right url.

Comment: @EJ2015 i have edited the html files to show the complete output for the page. there seems to be no background image mentioned in the html output in either the working or non-working pages. But teh image url comes from the stylesheet not the application layout. could this be causing it not to appear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching I stumbled upon a solution , but do not know why it worked.

`bundle exec rake assets:precompile` worked and made the images appear.

I had previously tried

```
bundle exec rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production
```

This solved my problem, but I am at a loss as to whether the command `bundle exec rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production` did not also solve the problem as I assume that it is doing the same thing as far as Heroku is concerned. The other confusing thing is that the html output remains the same as stated above in the original question. including the differences even though the pages look identical with images included.

If anyone could comment as to why this solution worked it could improve the answer for others with the same issue and also help me understand what went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You should keep your images in /assets/images. And use `image-url` instead of `url` in your css. This is the helper provided by Rails for the asset pipeline and will automatically generate the correct path to the file.

The name change to the file is due to the appended finger print from the asset pipeline, and asset pipeline generates these files into the /public folder as that's the root directory where static files are served. In development things are different and css and js are served separately. I think [this](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html) will help you understand.

Comment: changed background-image:url('menu.png') to background-image:image-url('menu.png'), but it made no different after pushing changes to heroku. also, yes, images are already in assets/images

Comment: Can try setting `config.serve_static_assets = true`. And you might need to `adjust config.public_file_server.enabled = ENV['RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES'].present?` if you're not using Nginx or Apache

Comment: where is the config.serve_static_assets setting? i dont see it in the production.rb file and what should i adjust in the config.public_file_server.enabled setting? also how can i find out if i am using Nginx or Apache and what are they?

Comment: These are web servers. You are not using them if you didn't set them up. Sorry but please forget about serve_static_assets. It's deprecated.  You can try changing the other to config.public_file_server.enabled = true (or better still just set ENV variable 'RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES' on heroku to be something nonblank). This should enable Rails from serving static files.

Comment: i tried config.public_file_server.enabled = true  but still no images. 'RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES' on heroku says 'enabled'

Comment: Check the fingerprints. It seems like rails is fingerprinting the asset, but the SCSS isn't picking that up. Check the name of the file in production, and then check the compiled CSS file. Like the others are saying, it kind of seems like there's a problem with the referencing. Try putting your application into production locally, precompile your assets, and see what happens.

Comment: @emptywalls if i changed teh name of the file in the css from background.png to background- longrandomstringofdigitsasnamedinpublic/assetsfolder.png would it then pick up the image?